# Can all programs be modeled as operations of elementary arithmetic operations on inputs?

Tags: logic, arithmetic, computational-complexity, computability

In mathematics and computabiltiy theory, we treat
all inputs and intermediate results and final
outputs as natural number. While algorithms/programs themselves are considered natural
numbers, here we treat these programs/functions/algorithms as just computable
functions.

The question is, when the function operates on an
input to produce an output, can we consider the
operation of function as using only a number of
arithmetic operations (addition, subtraction,
multiplication and division) on an input? Or does
the use of if/else make the aforementioned not
true?

If this is true, is the number of arithmetic
operations polynomially proportional to the
lowest time complexity bound possible for solving
a problem? (That is, if the lowest time complexity
is $\text{O(whatever)}$, then the number of
arithmetic operations is $\text{O(whatever}^k)$
where $k$ is some rational number.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a short and quick answer, an expert probably will give you more details in brief. The answer is No, and you are right, the if/else statements are necessary to make the language Turing complete. But remember that Peano arithmetic, a first order logic (which includes equivalents to if\else) axiomatization of arithmetic, is closely related to computability and Turing machines. Wikipedia gives a great summary of all this.

Answer (score 2):

The question is not very clear about the model of computation. But I think one easily shows that even a simple function like the characteristic function of the number $0$ (sending $0\mapsto1$, and $x\mapsto0$ for $x\neq0$) cannot be realised by a finite sequence of arithmetic operations.